# Is this common behaviour of the iPad device?

Tags: iphone, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have developed an iPad application which runs good in simulator with both orientations.

When i rotate the simulator , the corresponding view gets loaded according to the orientation.

But the same application when running on real iPad device,  when i rotate the device fastly, the corresponding view is not getting loaded. it takes time to load the correct view according to the device orientation.

why this happening? is this common behaviour in the ipad device?

Please let me know your views.

Answer (score 2):

It may be that the iPad does not have enough memory, unlike the simulator which runs in your computer and uses the computer's memory

Answer (score 2):

Does the view not load at all or just slowly?

Realize the iPad is nowhere near as powerful / fast as the Mac running your simulator.  Rotation is a relatively intensive task.  Also, depending on your memory footprint and if you have offscreen views that need to know about the rotation (to handle it appropriately), rotation often can trigger reloads of views that might have been unloaded previously by memory warnings, causing even further degradation in performance.

Finally, not loading at all could reflect upon issues in your orientation methods in your view controllers.

Comment: The view get loaded but when i rotate the device contentiously i get the wrong orientaion of view gets laoded.